# Is there a version of LockBox for Delphi-XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, lockbox-3

where can I find a version of LockBox for Delphi-XE

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work. It is not that hard.

1. Download from SVN. I'll refer to the base directory as `tplockbox`.
2. Go to the `tplockbox/trunc/packages` directory. Copy the `d2010` directory contents to a new directory named `XE`.
3. Rename `TP_LockBox_d2010.grouproj` to `TP_LockBox_XE.groupproj`
4. Open it, right click `TP_LockBox3_d2010.bpl`, go to Options, change "LIB suffix" from the Description section to `_XE`.
5. Do the same for the `dclTP_LockBox3_d2010.bpl` project
6. Adjust output paths and directories for all projects. I don't remember if I just went ahead and changed this globally.
7. Build and install `TP_LockBox3_XE.bpl` and `dclTP_LockBox3_XE.bpl` packages.

If you want the test cases to work, you'll have to modify the `tplockbox/trunc/test/uLockBox_TestCases.pas` file. There are some hard coded checks for an older version of DUnit than the one that comes with Delphi XE. You can just comment out these checks.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Delphi 2010 version available on [Songbeamer.com](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/).  Based on my experience porting Abbrevia to Delphi XE, it should work as-is.  You may want to rename the project files, but that should be about it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Songbeamer version is not the "official" sourceforge version.

Sean is managing both LockBox 2 and 3 code here: [link](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php)

Also see [this](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_parentId=64&topics_sort_mode=lastPost_desc&forumId=4) post on his forums.

Comment: Sadly, the "official" version of Lockbox 2 hasn't been updated past Delphi 7, and Lockbox 3 is a completely new (GPL) library.  They shouldn't be considered the same project.  If you have legacy code using Lockbox, the Songbeamer version is your best choice.

Comment: Lockbox 3 has LGPL licensing NOT GPL - big difference. In December 2010, I will be modifying the licensing to dual LGPL/MPL. In other words the user can choose to use and redistribute in either LGPL or MPL.

Comment: @Sean: I think it's great that you're developing *an* encryption library for Delphi, but IMO, if it's not compatible with Lockbox 2 you have no business calling it Lockbox 3.  The license "change" was only one small aspect of that.  If you have to completely rewrite your code to upgrade to a new version it's not the same library and shouldn't be presented as such.

Comment: I dont agree. There are plent of examples of popular product lines that break API when they move to a new major version. It is fair, valid and proper that LB3 be called that because it provides the same functionality and the administrative control has an unbroken line of descent to that of LB2. LB3 is in LB product line, but it is not the same library as LB2. It has never been presented as the same library. The home page and the about box is very clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the soureforge.net version, the TurboPower tools were updated by Nick Hodges and many others (IIRC it's even based on the songbeamer.com version):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tplockbox/

Comment: Unlike some of the other TurboPower projects, the SourceForge version of Lockbox never merged the Songbeamer.com changes.  Sean Durkin completely re-wrote the library for v3, broke the existing APIs, and changed the license to GPL.

Comment: See comment above. LGPL not GPL. LB2 uses MPL. LB3 has never "changed" its licensing. LB3 was developed from zero with LGPL.

Comment: License is now dual both LGPL and MPL