# SHA1 hashing in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, cryptography, delphi-xe, sha1

I'm in the process of implementing XML digital signatures. I'm starting with little steps, so right now I want to solve the problem of SHA-1 hashing.

There are lots of questions about this in SO:

1. [Digitially Sign Key with Lockbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783077/digitially-sign-key-with-lockbox)
2. [Encryption library for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402380/encryption-library-for-delphi)
3. [Convert this php digital signing to Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792541/convert-this-php-digital-signing-to-delphi)
4. [Delphi: is there a version of LockBox for Delphi-XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080825/delphi-is-there-a-version-of-lockbox-for-delphi-xe)
5. [Delphi 2010 Cryptography libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020216/delphi-2010-cryptography-libraries)

...and probably more. However, I'm using Delphi XE. So far, I've tried LockBox 2 (both the Songbeamer and Sourceforge versions), Lock Box 3, DCPCrypto2 and some others ([Hashes](http://delphi.jmrds.com/?q=node/36) is an easy to use unit which uses Windows crypto functions)

I prepared a small test rig that gives me the following:

**LockBox2**

```
FAILED: 1 ('abc') 
       Got: '9f04f41a848514162050e3d68c1a7abb441dc2b5'
  Expected: 'a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d'
FAILED: 2 ('abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq') 
       Got: '51d7d8769ac72c409c5b0e3f69c60adc9a039014'
  Expected: '84983e441c3bd26ebaae4aa1f95129e5e54670f1'
```

**LockBox3**

```
FAILED: 1 ('abc') 
       Got: '9f04f41a848514162050e3d68c1a7abb441dc2b5'
  Expected: 'a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d'
FAILED: 2 ('abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq') 
       Got: '51d7d8769ac72c409c5b0e3f69c60adc9a039014'
  Expected: '84983e441c3bd26ebaae4aa1f95129e5e54670f1'
```

**DCPCrypto2**

```
FAILED: 1 ('abc') 
       Got: '9f04f41a848514162050e3d68c1a7abb441dc2b5'
  Expected: 'a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d'
FAILED: 2 ('abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq') 
       Got: '51d7d8769ac72c409c5b0e3f69c60adc9a039014'
  Expected: '84983e441c3bd26ebaae4aa1f95129e5e54670f1'
```

**Hashes**

```
Test 1 passes
Test 2 passes
```

Have you succeeded in compile the mentioned libraries under Delphi XE and make them give the appropriate values? I'm particularly interested in **DCPCrypt2** `SelfTest` procedure.

**Edit**: I've added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929650/sha1-hashing-in-delphi-xe/4941040#4941040) with the fixed source code. Thank you all for your help, it is most appreciated.

Comment: Without sample code your question is meaningless.

Comment: +1 for the overview of libraries. Note that hashing is meant for binary data, not for strings (their binary representation depends on their encoding). I wrote a similar conclusion while [writing on MD5 hashing](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/delphi-md5-the-messagedigest_5-unit-has-been-there-since-delphi-2007/). (Reading the answers: that was the conclusion of the answers too <g>).

Comment: @Warren P - I'll update this answer with my code.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp - Dude, I'm just evaluating the SecureBlackBox toolkit, and I'm floored. Don't you have a nice, fat discount coupon laying around that you can give me? ;-)

Comment: @Leonardo yes, please contact me via our HelpDesk ( https://www.eldos.com/helpdesk/ )

Comment: @Leonardo, I saw your user feedback message and I will reply there. If you don't get e-mail, still use HelpDesk please

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Leonardo, i think which your problem is the `UNICODE` when you uses a function to hash a `string` you are passing a array (buffer) of bytes. so when you pass the `abc` string in Delphi XE, your are hashing a buffer like this `61 00 62 00 63 00` (Hex representation)

check this sample application which uses the Windows crypto functions from the `Jwscl library` (JEDI Windows Security Code Lib)

```
program Jwscl_TestHash;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  JwsclTypes,
  JwsclCryptProvider,
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

function GetHashString(Algorithm: TJwHashAlgorithm; Buffer : Pointer;Size:Integer) : AnsiString;
var
  Hash: TJwHash;
  HashSize: Cardinal;
  HashData: Pointer;
  i       : Integer;
begin
  Hash := TJwHash.Create(Algorithm);
  try
    Hash.HashData(Buffer,Size);
    HashData := Hash.RetrieveHash(HashSize);
    try
        SetLength(Result,HashSize*2);
        BinToHex(PAnsiChar(HashData),PAnsiChar(Result),HashSize);
    finally
      TJwHash.FreeBuffer(HashData);
    end;
  finally
    Hash.Free;
  end;
end;


function GetHashSHA(FBuffer : AnsiString): AnsiString;
begin
   Result:=GetHashString(haSHA,@FBuffer[1],Length(FBuffer));
end;

function GetHashSHA_Unicode(FBuffer : String): String;
begin
   Result:=GetHashString(haSHA,@FBuffer[1],Length(FBuffer)*SizeOf(Char));
end;

begin
 try
     Writeln(GetHashSHA('abc'));
     Writeln(GetHashSHA('abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq'));
     Writeln(GetHashSHA_Unicode('abc'));
     Writeln(GetHashSHA_Unicode('abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq'));
     Readln;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
        Readln;
    end;
 end;

end.
```

this return

`abc` AnsiString

A9993E364706816ABA3E25717850C26C9CD0D89D

`abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq` AnsiString

84983E441C3BD26EBAAE4AA1F95129E5E54670F1 for

`abc` unicode

9F04F41A848514162050E3D68C1A7ABB441DC2B5

`abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq` Unicode

51D7D8769AC72C409C5B0E3F69C60ADC9A039014

Comment: Great answer. I see now. I guess what tipped me off in the wrong direction was the DCPCrypt2 SelfTest function, which returns false.

Comment: Good tip. I didn't know you could use the crypto libs in Windows, using JWSCL wrappers.

Answer (score 19):

My Cygwin command-prompt tells me it is indeed Unicode that's confusing you:

```
~$ printf 'a\0b\0c\0' | sha1sum
9f04f41a848514162050e3d68c1a7abb441dc2b5 *-
~$ printf 'abc' | sha1sum
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d *-
```

Comment: @Leonardo I expect you're being sarcastic, but it does show the utility of Cygwin for testing these kinds of hypotheses - md5sum, sha1sum, and openssl for a lot more.

Comment: No, I'm not being sarcastic at all! I accepted RRUZ's answer because it is more complete, but this is a terrific answer. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't have said it was more complete, it's just more verbose which isn't necessarily better. Anyway, I'm not trying to knock RRUZ, but I'm with Barry, all good developers should learn to use powerful command line tools so that they can get tasks like this done more efficiently.

Comment: I agree completely re: different tools. I loved this answer, it was really clear, and actually I read this before reading RRUZ's and got the answer immediatly. If I could accept two answers for one question I would! (RRUZ answer is not just more verbose.)

Answer (score 6):

Could the expected value be for an ANSI string and the hash you are getting is for a unicode string?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so it was Unicode issues. Just in case you want to know, this is my Unit1.pas source. You need a form with a memo and a button. Requires DCPCrypt2, LockBox2, LockBox3 and the Hashes unit.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, LbCipher, LbClass, StdCtrls, DCPcrypt2, DCPsha1, Hashes,
  uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary, uTPLb_BaseNonVisualComponent, uTPLb_Hash;

type
  THashProc = reference to procedure(src: AnsiString; var output: AnsiString);

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    btnTest: TButton;
    function Display(Buf: TBytes): String;

    procedure LockBox2Test;
    procedure LockBox3Test;
    procedure DCPCrypto2Test;
    procedure HashesTest;
    procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure RunTests(Name: String; HashFunc: THashProc);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses uTPLb_StreamUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LockBox2Test;
  LockBox3Test;
  DCPCrypto2Test;
  HashesTest;
end;

procedure TForm1.DCPCrypto2Test;
begin
  RunTests('DCPCrypto2', procedure(src: AnsiString; var output: AnsiString)
  var
    Digest: TSHA1Digest;
    Bytes : TBytes;
    SHA1 : TDCP_sha1;
  begin
    SHA1 := TDCP_sha1.Create(nil);
    SHA1.Init;
    SHA1.UpdateStr(src);
    SHA1.Final(Digest);
    SHA1.Destroy;
    SetLength(Bytes, 20);
    Move(Digest, Bytes[0], 20);
    output := Form1.Display(Bytes);
  end);
end;

function TForm1.Display(Buf: TBytes): String;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to 19 do
    Result := Result + Format('%0.2x', [Buf[i]]);
  Result := LowerCase(Trim(Result));
end;

procedure TForm1.HashesTest;
begin
  RunTests('Hashes', procedure(src: AnsiString; var output: AnsiString)
  begin
    output := CalcHash2(src, haSHA1)
  end)
end;

procedure TForm1.LockBox2Test;
begin
  RunTests('LockBox2', procedure(src: AnsiString; var output: AnsiString)
    var
      Digest: TSHA1Digest;
      Bytes : TBytes;
      SHA1 : TLbSHA1;
    begin
      SHA1 := TLbSHA1.Create(nil);
      SHA1.HashStringA(src);
      SHA1.GetDigest(Digest);
      SHA1.Destroy;
      SetLength(Bytes, 20);
      Move(Digest, Bytes[0], 20);
      output := Form1.Display(Bytes);
    end);
end;

procedure TForm1.LockBox3Test;
begin
  RunTests('LockBox3', procedure(src: AnsiString; var output: AnsiString)
    var
      Digest: TSHA1Digest;
      bytes : TBytes;
      P, Sz: integer;
      aByte: byte;
      s: string;
      SHA1 : THash;
      Lib : TCryptographicLibrary;
    begin
      Lib := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
      SHA1 := THash.Create(nil);
      SHA1.CryptoLibrary := Lib;
      SHA1.HashId := 'native.hash.SHA-1';
      SHA1.Begin_Hash;
      SHA1.HashAnsiString(src);
      if not assigned(SHA1.HashOutputValue) then
          output := 'nil'
      else
      begin
        SetLength(Bytes, 20);
        Sz := SHA1.HashOutputValue.Size;
        if Sz <> 20 then
          output := Format('wrong size: %d', [Sz])
        else
        begin
          P := 0;
          SHA1.HashOutputValue.Position := 0;
          while SHA1.HashOutputValue.Read(aByte, 1) = 1 do
          begin
            bytes[P] := aByte;
            Inc(P);
          end;
          output := Form1.Display(Bytes);
        end;
      end;
      SHA1.Destroy;
      Lib.Destroy;
    end)
end;

procedure TForm1.RunTests(Name: String; HashFunc: THashProc);
var
  i: Integer;
  Tests: array [1 .. 2, 1 .. 2] of AnsiString;
  src, res: AnsiString;
  expected: String;
begin
  // http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/testdata/
  Tests[1][1] := 'abc';
  Tests[1][2] := 'a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d';

  Tests[2][1] := 'abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq';
  Tests[2][2] := '84983e441c3bd26ebaae4aa1f95129e5e54670f1';

  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('**' + Name + '**');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');

  for i := 1 to 2 do
  begin
    src := Tests[i][1];
    expected := Tests[i][2];
    HashFunc(src, res);
    res := Trim(LowerCase(res));
    if res = expected then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('    Test %d passes', [i]))
    end
    else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('    FAILED: %d (''%s'') ', [i, src]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('           Got: ''%s''', [res]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('      Expected: ''%s''', [expected]));
    end;
  end;

end;

end.
```