# sha1 checksum in delphi

Tags: delphi, sha1

I have the following code written in delphi.

```
with TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create do begin
    st2.Position := 0;
    Digest := HashValue( st2 );
    SetLength( Hash, 16 );
    Move( Digest, Hash[1], 16);
    Free;
end;
```

I need to convert that to use SHA1 hash. I couldn't find SHA1 type in the library. Can anyone help? I have looked for help on the internet but couldn't find any.

Comment: sha1 is not secure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using Indy 9, which does not support SHA1.  SHA1 (and a few other hashes, including several other SHAs) was added in Indy 10.  The interface for `TIdHash` was also re-written in Indy 10.  Amongst other changes, the `HashValue()` method was replaced with new `Hash...()` and `Hash...AsHex()` methods (`HashString(AsHex)`, `HashStream(AsHex)`, `HashBytes(AsHex)`), eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdHash, IdHashMessageDigest;

var
  Hash: TIdBytes;
begin
  with TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create do
  try
    st2.Position := 0;
    Hash := HashStream( st2 );
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  // use Hash as needed...
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., IdHash, IdHashSHA;

var
  Hash: TIdBytes;
begin
  with TIdHashSHA1.Create do
  try
    st2.Position := 0;
    Hash := HashStream( st2 );
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  // use Hash as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, 
Thanks for your time. I will use it and see how it works for me. I am using Delphi 2005. Can you suggest from where do I fetch IdGlobal.pas as the one I have generate lot of "Undeclared Identifier" errors?

Comment: @MKK such as? it is not enough to just get a newer IdGlobal.pas by itself, you need to get a newer  ersion of the entire Indy library as a whole.

Answer (score 4):

See here:

https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/high-performance-hash-library/

[SHA1 hashing in Delphi XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929650/sha1-hashing-in-delphi-xe)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/sha1implementat/

http://www.colorfultyping.com/generating-a-sha-1-checksum-for-a-given-class-type/

BTW, you didn't mention your Delphi version. If you are using a modern version (XE onwards), I suppose that its standard libraries should support SHA-1, MD5, etc.

You could do it like this:

```
uses IdHashSHA;

function SHA1FromString(const AString: string): string;
var
  SHA1: TIdHashSHA1;
begin
  SHA1 := TIdHashSHA1.Create;
  try
    Result := SHA1.HashStringAsHex(AString);
  finally
    SHA1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Answers containing nothing but off-site links are not acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, in latest Delphi versions You can try:

```
uses
  System.Hash;

...

function getHashCode(const s : string) : string;
begin
  Result := THashSHA1.GetHashString(s);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In older versions also (tested in maXbox4):

```
 function SHA1FromFile(const filename: string): string;
 var SHA1: TIdHashSHA1;  
 fs: TFileStream;
 begin
   SHA1:= TIdHashSHA1.Create;
   fs:= TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
   try
     result:= SHA1.AsHex(SHA1.hashvalue1((fs),0,fs.size));
   finally
     SHA1.Free;
     fs.Free;
   end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more options:

http://www.spring4d.org

```
unit Spring.Cryptography.SHA;

TSHA1 = class(THashAlgorithmBase, ISHA1)
```

---

http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/HomePage

```
unit LbProc;
procedure StreamHashSHA1(var Digest : TSHA1Digest; AStream : TStream);
procedure FileHashSHA1(var Digest : TSHA1Digest; const AFileName : string);
```